# How do I convert APK to TPK using Tizen Studio

Tags: apk, tizen, samsung-smart-tv

I have the Skylink SK Apk and I want to install it onto my Samsung 2019 55" Tizen TV.

Samsung said I need Skylink to send me the TPK and Skylink say its Samsung problem ??

How do I convert my APK into a TPK , or does anyone have Skylink Live SK TV TPK File.  Or is there away of install APK onto Tizen TV, I know I will have to use SDB upload process not ADB as some suggest

Comment: APK is made for Android OS. TPK is made for Tizen OS. It means APK can't be converted to TPK by some tools. You need to find Tizen Version of Skylink Live.

Answer (score -1):

A solution is to reset your tv to factory settings and then to set up the ISP location to whatever country Skylink is available in during the first boot.
There is a little manipulation to do during the setup but everything is explained very well in this youtube video : https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9PPlan7lVzc
Skylink will then be available when searching for apps to install in apps menu.
Took me less than 5 minutes (French dude here with a Czech girl using Skylink as well ;) )

Cheers

Comment: Thank you, but you lose the app once you go back to English UK mode

Comment: Indeed, but though my TV is now in " Czech mode" after the reboot , all the menu / navigation are still in french so I intend to let it in this mode. I'm using other apps (Spotify, YouTube...) and fortunately those are also available in Czech mode, so i didn't feel the need to switch back to french. I guess you need one or more apps only available in UK? Maybe you can try finding a country offering both skylink and the app(s) you are using in UK. Otherwise having the tpk seems indeed the way to go but for this i can't help you..